# Getting a URL with an authenticity token using python

Tags: python, authentication, urllib

I am trying to read a web page using a get request in python.
The original URL is [given here](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/385228.On_Liberty). I found out that the information I am interested in is in a subpage with [this URL](https://www.goodreads.com/book/reviews/385228.On_Liberty?authenticity_token=XXX&hide_last_page=true&language_code=en&page=4) (I replaced the authenticity token with XXX).

I tried using the second URL in my script but I get a 406 error. Can you suggest what am I doing wrong? Is the authenticity token for preventing scraping? if so, can I work around it?

```
import urllib.request

url = ...
agent={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url,headers=agent)
data = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

Thanks!

PS, This is how I get the URL using Chrome:

First I browse to https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/385228.On_Liberty

Then I open Chrome's developer tools: three dots -> more tools -> developer tools. Choose the network tab.

Then I go to the bottom of the page (just after the last review) and click "next".

In the tool window choose the request and in the header I get the Request URL: https://www.goodreads.com/book/reviews/385228?csm_scope=&hide_last_page=true&language_code=en&page=2&authenticity_token=XXX

Comment: Could you please include the url that you used? You can replace token with other string

Comment: This is how I get the URL using Chrome:

First I browse to https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/385228.On_Liberty

Then I open Chrome's developer tools: (three dots -> more tools -> developer tools. Choose the network tab.

Then I go to the bottom of the page (just after the last review) and click "next".

In the tool window choose the request and in the header I get the Request URL: https://www.goodreads.com/book/reviews/385228?csm_scope=&amp;hide_last_page=true&amp;language_code=en&amp;page=2&authenticity_token=XXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to update your headers to include one more item, like:

```
headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}
req = urllib.request.Request(url,headers= headers)
```

I managed to get `200 OK` back when adding that header, however, the response you'll get back from this endpoint might not really be what you need in the end, since it is a piece of JavaScript code which in return updates the HTML page. You can still use it in some way, but it's very dirty approach and might complicate things a lot.

What information do you need exactly? There might be a different approach than using that "problematic" response from your second URL.

Comment: The information I need is the list of ratings (The username of the reviewer and the number of stars this user gave)

Comment: Try to add the header in your request and let me know if that helps. I can take a better look at alternative approach later if you'll still need it!

Comment: Yes, this worked! I accepted the answer.

Can you help me with one more small thing? When I tried 
```
data = webUrl.read().decode('utf-8')
print(data)
```

I see that in the page there are encoded characters such as \u0026quot;

Is there a way to decode it differently to get a cleaner text?

Thanks!

Comment: In your particular case, you can decode that string in this way: `bytes(data, 'utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')`, however, that might not guarantee a 100% correct output due to some other factors, but I believe it should help you already with "prettifying" your string.